# ION library print Request that is sent to PHP server

Tags: android, android-ion

I am using **ION library** for my project. Now I am facing some problem in sending the **parameters** to the server. The **parameters** are not being sent to the server sometime.

I wanted to know whether my **parameters** are being sent to my server properly

How do I print the **Request object** that **ION** send to my server, so that I can view the parameters

Comment: Why down vote ? Could you please exaplain

Comment: did you find any solution for this ???

Answer (score -1):

For this thing you have print all the parameter throw your server file as response and using android you have to print response into Log

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
.uploadProgressBar(uploadProgressBar)
.setMultipartParameter("goop", "noop")
.setMultipartFile("archive", "application/zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip"))
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        Log.d("data",result);
    }
});
```

I have checked in this way.

Comment: The results only consist of the Response thrown by the server. I want my request to the server.

Comment: suppose you are passing userid throw ION then you have to set response as userid in server side file. so when you are calling that file you get what you already passed into response. @karthikkolanji

Comment: Sorry . Please suggest me some way that I can do it in Android side itself. Like Retrofit library